# How to create a marker of fixed size relative to map in folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I have images I want to display on a map. At the moment, I am using `Marker` with `CustomIcon` like

```
marker = folium.Marker(location=(lat,long),icon=folium.features.CustomIcon(sprite_url,icon_size=(64,64)))
map.add_child(marker)
```

However, the icon is always at 64x64. I would love to have it where it is at 64 by 64 at say, zoom level 16, and if it is zoomed out or in it is smaller or larger, respectively.

Is this possible? And if so, how would I do it? I've read about `imageOverlay` but from the [documentation I read](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/ImageOverlay.ipynb) it sounds like I could only use that to overlay one image across the entire map, and I have thousands of data points to plot.

Answer (score 1):

It is not inherently supported by folium and chances are it will not be for the foreseeable future or ever, though there appears to be some wiggle room.

[See here the answer to when the question was first raised in 2015:](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay/issues/6)

> A wider answer to this question before closing:
>
> When zooming two things can happen: either one reprojects the element
> geometries into the new zoom level (elements features like size remain
> constant) or one scales the whole overlay (but then elements
> shrink/expand and one needs to adjust for that if it's desirable).
>
> Since reprojection of the geometries is computationally more
> demanding, scaling and adjusting the size of elements is an easier and
> quicker way:
>
> ```
> ...
> updSel.
>     .attr("r", 5 / this._scale)
> ```
>
> The code above will set a radius (for SVG circle element) to always be
> 5 pixels.